# Type deduction with auto at runtime

Tags: c++, auto, type-deduction

all. Very quick question. Why statement like below can be compiled with recent gcc or MSVC, but same thing with custom types is not possible?

`const auto& a = isParamFP16 ? 0 : "aaa";` - possible
`const auto& a = isParamFP16 ? paramFP32 : paramFP16;` - impossible (`error C2446: ':': no co nversion from 'const T' to 'const T'` for MSVC and `operands to ?: have different types ‘const param<FP32>’ and ‘const param<FP16>’` for gcc)

I know that all types should be resolved at compile time, but why first variant works?

Thank you.

Comment: `"aaa"` is a pointer, and so is `0`!

Comment: @NikitaDemodov To be more precise, `"aaa"` is an array which will decay to a pointer, and `0` can be used as a null pointer (in a context where pointers are expected).

Answer (score 6):

With

```
const auto& a = isParamFP16 ? 0 : "aaa";
```

`"aaa"`'s type will decay to a `const char *`.  `0` is an `int`, but it is also a valid value for a `const char *` since it is a null pointer constant.  That means the compiler will deduce the entire conditional operation as yielding a `const char *` no matter which value is returned.

With

```
const auto& a = isParamFP16 ? paramFP32 : paramFP16;
```

You have a `param<FP32>` for the first result and a `param<FP16>` for the second.  There is no way to convert one to the other, so a compiler error is issued as the conditional operator can only yield a single type.

Comment: `std::is_pointer<decltype(a)>::value` yields `false`

Comment: @Raildex That is because `a` is declared as a reference type.  Try `std::is_pointer<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(a)>>::value`

Answer (score 3):

The first variant works, because an integer literal `0` is a *null pointer constant*, which means it can be implicitly converted to any pointer type (resulting in a null pointer value).

So, `0` can be converted to `const char*` and the string literal `"aaa"` decays to a pointer `const char*`. The types match, and so the type of `a` will be `char const* const&`.

Try it with any other value, e.g. `1` or some math e.g. `1-1`, and it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

The last two operands of the ? expression must have identical types (to an implicit conversion) so that the type of the whole expression can be deduced at compile-time. In the first case they do (pointer). Not in the second.